# Where can we advertise?

Tags: discussion

Since we never got an answer to [this](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/a/84/167), I'm bringing it up as a separate question:

**This site needs more eyeballs**, specifically ones that are qualified to answer questions here. (Our unanswered rate is hovering at around 10 percent.) One way to do this would be to advertise in industry publications.

- Is Stack Exchange willing to foot the bill for this? (Maybe a Stack Exchange employee could chime in about this?)
- What publications or websites would be appropriate for this? (I'll start some CW answers where we can put down publications, and let's indicate why they're appropriate.)

Answer (score 1):

### Audio

**[TapeOp](http://www.tapeop.com/)** - This magazine/website specializes in audio, and focuses on gear as well as personalities and the process behind recording and engineering.

- Advantages: Readers here are going to be fairly intense, and I imagine professional.

**[Logic Pro Help](http://www.logicprohelp.com/)**

- Advantages: Good quality, very focused. This site has a lot of good information, and has very good forums that have helped me learn a lot about Logic.
- Disadvantages: It's a forum, and sort of a competitor. It also has a smaller audience.

**[Studio Central](http://studio-central.com/)** and its associated **[forums](http://studio-central.com/phpbb/index.php)**

- Advantages: The site itself, especially [Tweak's Guide to the Home and Project Studio](http://www.tweakheadz.com/guide.htm) - has a lot of good information about home and enthusiast setups, and there are some real pros that hang out on the boards here. The site has very broad appeal, and deals with all manner of hardware and software.
- Disadvantages: Newbies and forum rats abound, and the forums are lower-traffic in some ways than one would think. I've posted many a question here that took days or months to get an answer.

**[Sound on Sound magazine](http://www.soundonsound.com/)**

- Advantages: Good quality, generally respected in professional audio. They have something of a reputation for only discussing products and services they already like.
- Disadvantages: Probably expensive. An advertisement might not be as effective as a mention from one of the editors.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest letting people over at [GearSlutz](http://gearslutz.com) know about it. It's a forum filled with mostly professional audio engineers, and most of them are more than qualified to answer the sorts of questions I've seen on this site.

Comment: Could be touchy though.  I could see another site looking at that as kind of poaching.  If, for instance they get ad dollars based on site traffic, then they would likely frown upon another site taking traffic away.  This is not to say that the users of that site would not be a good fit here.  I would tend to agree with you on that point.  Just saying it may require something more delicate than advertising :)

Comment: Also, just noticed this in their [faq](http://www.gearslutz.com/board/faq.php): "17. You may not “fish” (recruit) for users/readers for any other pro audio forum or blog. If you are caught doing this you risk account suspension and the URL will be added to our “censor” list. "